# ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.update) Failed to impersonate when terraform runs impersonating as a second account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, impersonation, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I am getting the following error (Please see below) when I run my terraform apply.

I am running Terraform 12.x.

GCP Cloud Build runs in a different project other than project-abcd (where these accounts are)

My terraform code tries execute a gcloud command in a GCP cloud build container. It does so by impersonating as **composer-bq-sa@prj-abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

The service account that terraform runs as is:
terraform_service_account = "**org-terraform@abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**"
(before impersonating)

This IAM account (**org-terraform@abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**) (NOT service account) has the following role bindings (TOTAL 9):
(There is no Service Account with that email)

```
Composer Administrator
Compute Network Admin
Service Account Token Creator
Owner
Access Context Manager Admin
Security Admin
Service Account Admin
Logs Configuration Writer
Security Center Notification Configurations Editor
```

The service account (**composer-bq-sa@prj-abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**) has as one of its members: **org-terraform@abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**
When I look at the screen titled "Members with access to this service account" and look at **org-terraform@abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com** , I see that it has the following role-bindings (ONLY 4):

```
Service Account Token Creator
Owner
Security Admin
Service Account Admin
```

Why am I getting the error below even though IAM account has apparently the right roles and it is one of the members of the service account it is impersonating as?

ERROR

```
module.gcloud_composer_bucket_env_var.null_resource.run_command[0] (local-exec): WARNING: This command 
is using service account impersonation. All API calls will be executed as [**composer-bq-sa@prj-abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**].
module.gcloud_composer_bucket_env_var.null_resource.run_command[0] (local-exec): ERROR: 
(gcloud.composer.environments.update) Failed to impersonate [**composer-bq-sa@prj-abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com**]. Make sure the account that's trying to impersonate it has access to the service account itself and the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role.
```

Comment: Have a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) and manually check everything Terraform does. If you encounter more errors, please update the question.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the issue was that terraform@abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com was not given explicit permission to impersonate composer-bq-sa@prj-abcd.iam.gserviceaccount.com. That document you refereed had the instructions to do so. If you add the above as the answer, I will accept it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recapping:
In order to grant user permission to impersonate a Service Account follow instructions listed in [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#allow-impersonation) document.
Depending on the use case, you may grant user following roles:

- `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`
- `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`
- `roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser`